# Statistic in template show CombinedExpression for one field

Tags: python, django

I have problem with template render. It shows statistic table for Document model (counts of views, downloads, likes, dislikes), but view_count in final html is not a number, it's an CombinedExpression object like `F(view_count) + Value(1)`. Perhaps the reason for my problem is that I am updating a statistic and adding it to the template in the same part of the code.

```py
# views.py
class DocumentDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.statistic = FileStatistic.objects.get(document=self.object)
        self.statistic.increment_field('view_count')
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object, statistic=self.statistic)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

# models.py
# NOTE: this model class is OneToOneField referenced in Document model class.
class FileStatistic(models.Model):
    
    download_count = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name='Количество скачиваний'
    )
    view_count = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name='Количество просмотров'
    )
    like_count = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name='Количество лайков'
    )
    dislike_count = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name='Количество дизлайков'
    )

    def increment_field(self, field_name: str) -> None:
        setattr(self, field_name, models.F(field_name) + 1)
        self.save(update_fields=[field_name])
```

```html
        <table class="table table-borderless table-sm">
            <thread>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" scope='col'>Число скачиваний</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope='col'>Число просмотров</th>
                    <th class="text-center" score='col'>Число лайков</th>
                    <th class="text-center" score='col'>Число дизлайков</th>
                </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center border-top">{{statistic.download_count}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center border-top">{{statistic.view_count}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center border-top">{{statistic.like_count}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center border-top">{{statistic.dislike_count}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was this: add `self.statistic.refresh_from_db()` after `self.statistic.increment_field('view_count')` in DocumentDetailView get method.